# Why can't I get the year, month, day of a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have this code I got the current date, however I can't seem to get the tuple to datetime.
tup[0] is the year, tup[1] is the month, tup[2] is the day.
Why can't I return the year, month and day?

```
import datetime

def get_current_date():
    date = datetime.date.today()
    return date.year, date.month, date.day

def tuple_to_datetime(tup: tuple):
    datetime.date(tup[0],tup[1],tup[2])
    return datetime.date


date_tuple = get_current_date()
date_datetime = tuple_to_datetime(date_tuple)

print(date_tuple)
print(date_datetime.year)
print(date_datetime.month)
print(date_datetime.day)

(2020, 10, 5)
<attribute 'year' of 'datetime.date' objects>
<attribute 'month' of 'datetime.date' objects>
<attribute 'day' of 'datetime.date' objects>
```

Output I want:

```
(2020, 10, 5)
2020
10
5
```

Comment: In `tuple_to_datetime` you don't return the specific `datetime.date` you created, you return the entire class object `datetime.date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually return the `datetime.date` class, you need to return the instance you created

```
def tuple_to_datetime(tup: tuple):
    return datetime.date(tup[0], tup[1], tup[2])
```